# How to skip elements which are null while using xmlWriter in c#

Tags: c#, xml, enums

I have written a WriteXml method

```
public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
            if (this.value != null)
            {
                var type = this.value.GetType();

                var memInfo = type.GetMember(this.value.ToString());

                if (memInfo.Length > 0)
                {
                    var attrs = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes<XmlEnumAttribute>();

                    if (attrs != null && attrs.IsNotEmpty())
                    {
                        writer.WriteValue(attrs.ToString());

                        return;
                    }
                }
                writer.WriteValue(this.value.ToString());
            }
        }
```

The main purpose of the whole class I have written is for custom enums. The issue is when the serialize is called in between a service there are few custom enums which uses class and if there is a special value or spaces in the enum it gets its attribute and returns and if there is a normal enum then also it works. But if there is a null in the enum value it is sending back null which is creating empty tags which I don't want to create.

How to  not serialize the values which have null ?

Empty Tags are nothing but `<XYZ/>`

I have lot of values under enums like

```
insurance
product 
name 
N/A
Last Days
```

The above all of them are retrieved but if there is a null I don't want to serialize a value.

To be simple, If `this.value` is returning a null I don't want to serialize it.

To add it to the above thing, All the values I get are not Enum. So only enum are using my custom class but not the different ones.